# Compare the number of each line in a file

Tags: c

I started learning C, the variables, functions, memory and structures were ok but now I'm stuck with very simple exercises about files

Example

I have a file with a name and a grade in each line. Something like

```
asdfgh 1.5
asdfg h 2
a 0.5
```

I've learned how to read each line and I can write a program that reads every line and outputs the number of lines, etc but what I want to learn now is how to isolate the numbers to compare them later. For example to get the maximum or the average, it doesn't matter. Something like

```
The max number is 2
```

I'm using fgets and sscanf but at this point I'm very confused with all the tutorials I already watched.

Any simple example or tutorial anyone can share?

I'm reading about strtok, it seems to be useful for what I want but I'm not understanding the theory to apply it for what I want and the videos I watched made me even more confused

I can open the file, read the file and read each line until the end of the file but storing the chars that have numbers in it to later compare them is the part that I don't get

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char name[1000];
float number = 0;
int lines = 0;
char line[1000];

do {
    fgets(line, 1000, stdin);
    lines++
} while (line[0] != '\n');

return 0;
```

Comment: Please use the idiomatic `while(fgets(line, 1000, stdin) != NULL)`. The test for `line[0]` might never be `'\n'`.

Comment: If the number is always in the last position and not followed by any white spaces, you can use `strrchr()` to find its beginning and then `atof()` or `strtod()` to convert the string to a number.

Comment: Your code's incomplete, plus it doesn't actually use sscanf. It would help to have your actual code and an explanation of what specific problems you're having with it.

Comment: If the number can truly be any token on the line, use `fgets` to get the line. Then, loop on `strtok(...," \t\n")` and look at the first char of the token. If it's a digit (e.g. `isdigit`), then decode it with `strtol`.

Comment: Aside: please don't make this a "shifting sand" question in response to comments. Post the actual code you used, not guesses. I meant `while`, not `do...while`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I guess I need to study more theory before starting doing exercises. I thought that seeing the solution of this exercise could be helpful to make me understand it all better but I think the theory is missing here since apparently not even this little code I wrote is right. I'm going to look into strrchr() as you suggested. Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers may begin with `'0'-'9'`, `'+'`, `'-'`, `'.'`,`'I'`, `'i'` (Infinity), `'N'`, `'n'` (NAN), *white-spaces* and other implementation specific values like `','`.  Perhaps even ` in the future. <sup>*1</sup>

Rather than look for just the first numeric character, use `strtod()` repeatedly and let that function validate the text as a *number*.

```
const char *s = line;
char *endptr;  // Location to store end of conversion.
bool found = false;
double d;
for (; *s; s++) {
  errno = 0;
  d = strtod(s, &endptr);
  if (s == endptr) continue;  // No conversion.
  // If following is not a space nor a null character ...
  if (!isspace((unsigned char) *endptr) && *endptr) continue;
  // You may want to test for range or skip this.
  if (errno == ERANGE) continue;
  found = true;
  break;
}
if (found) {
  printf("Found %g at <%.*s>\n", d, (int)(endptr - s), s);
}
```

---

<sup>*1</sup> The [next version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x) of C may allow new things like a *' digit separator*, binary input, etc.  By using standard functions to validate, your code is ready for the future - this reduces maintenance and keeps code up to date..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) to find the first numeric digit.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char s[] = "hello world 123";
    size_t n = strcspn(s, "1234567890");

    printf("%s\n", &s[n]);

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
123
```

If we have a pointer to this substring, we can then use [`strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) to convert it to a `double`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char s[] = "hello world 123";
    size_t n = strcspn(s, "1234567890");

    printf("%lf\n", strtod(&s[n], NULL));

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
123
```

Of course, you should probably also error check to determine *if* a numeric digit was found.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char s[] = "hello world";
    size_t n = strcspn(s, "1234567890");

    if (!s[n]) {
        printf("Numeric digit not found.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%lf\n", strtod(&s[n], NULL));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to study this since I didn't know about strtol() or strtod() but it's an easy and understandable code. I think I can "play" with this to learn more about files. Thank you :)

Comment: Chris, consider inputs like `".123"`, `"-456"`.  This answer reports `123` and `456`.

Comment: I agree. Your solution is more robust. I think there may be some value to the answer I've provided nonetheless, so will not delete this. UV for you, though.